# stylelint error in node_modules/meow/build/index.js:29

Tags: stylelint

While inspection css files with phpstorm 2023.3 and

node v20.11.0
npm 10.3.0

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "grunt": "^1.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^3.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "^5.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^5.2.2",
    "stylelint": "^16.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-recess-order": "^4.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^14.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^6.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-xbsoftware": "^5.0.0-alpha.3",
    "grunt-banner": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^1.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^5.0.0",
    "grunt-css": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-json-minify": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-minjson": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-remove-comments": "^0.1.6",
    "grunt-remove-logging": "^0.2.0",
    "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^36.0.0",
    "uglify-js": "^3.17.4"
  }
```

getting this error:

node_modules/meow/build/index.js:29
description &&= help ? `\n  ${description}\n` : `\n${description}`;
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&&='
at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)

Process finished with exit code 1

maybe somebody got a similar problem and solved it?!

Thankyou
Michael

Comment: Please check your PHPStorm settings which Node version is used by the IDE (Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js)

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot..  nodejs has been 14.x now its 20.11.0

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when running Node 14 or earlier, but the dependencies require Node 16 or later. You are experiencing this issue in PHPStorm, so check the settings for the used Node version: `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js`

Comment: Yes, Thank you that was the problem... Everything runs fine now! :-)